# Fathom syzygy browsing tool

Tags: programming, tablebases

I'm trying to make syzygy browsing tool **fathom.exe** work. If you have experience with this, please let me know. I tried million of combinations of tokens to format the position command and the program always returns empty string.

When I run this command

```
FILE* pipe = _popen("c:\\fathom.exe --help", "r");
```

program returns this info string:

```
usage: c:\fathom.exe [--help] [--path=PATH] [--test] FEN

WHERE:
FEN
    The position (as a FEN string) to be probed.
--help
    Print this helpful message.
--path=PATH
    Set the tablebase PATH string.
--test
    Print the result only.  Useful for scripts.

DESCRIPTION:
This program is a stand-alone Syzygy tablebase probe tool.  The
program takes as input a FEN string representation of a chess
position and outputs a PGN representation of the probe result.

In addition to the standard fields, the output PGN represents the
following information:
- Result: "1-0" (white wins), "1/2-1/2" (draw), or "0-1" (black wins)
- The Win-Draw-Loss (WDL) value for the next move: "Win", "Draw",
  "Loss", "CursedWin" (win but 50-move draw) or "BlessedLoss" (loss
  but 50-move draw)
- The Distance-To-Zero (DTZ) value (in plys) for the next move
- WinningMoves: The list of all winning moves
- DrawingMoves: The list of all drawing moves
- LosingMoves: The list of all losing moves

The PGN contains a pseudo "principle variation" of Syzygy vs. Syzygy
for the input position.  Each PV move is rational with respect to
preserving the WDL value.  The PV does not represent the shortest
mate nor the most natural human moves.
```

Can you write me please an **exact string command** to analyse for example

4k3/4n3/8/8/4K3/8/1B2B3/8 w - - 0 1

My wdl folder is C:/Tablebases/Syzygy/wdl

My dtz folder is C:/Tablebases/Syzygy/dtz

Comment: Please note it's not possible to make it work unless you copy your files into the same directory.

Comment: I'm now looking at it and I must first make sure that operating system or antivirus doesn't block the program under some circumstances...

Comment: Don't bother to check. Your output means your usage is wrong. I have seen it before. If your anti-virus blocks it, it wouldn't even run.

Comment: Right now even the exact line with --help that worked at time of writing the post doesn't work. SmartScreen woke up and blocked it suddenly. I think I should check what's going on.

Comment: Please close all anti-virus and other related programs just for testing. Fathom is safe and open-source for you to run.

Comment: I trust it and hopefully my system now trusts it too as both antivirus and smart screen filter are off. --help command is functional now so I can go check the command string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50887/discussion-between-hoacin-and-student-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience working with Fathom in one of my iOS apps. Look at my recent post:

http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=62378

My command was: `fathom --path=YOUR_PATH --test "FEN_STRING"`

- Substitute `YOUR_PATH` with your path. You must have both WDL and DTZ files in the same directory.
- Substitute `FEN_STRING` with your FEN string. You will need the quotation mark.

My console session posted in the link:

[image]